# proguard crash with gson library

Tags: android, jar, proguard

using proguard and the app crashes on start,  the correct line was added to fix this problem with the added gson library

```
 -libraryjars /libs/gson-2.2.4.jar
```

and it did not work, I even added it for the android-support-v4.jar and no change, even though i am not using the support library,  this jar is in the /libs folder so I did the same with this file and no change, the app still crashes on start.

-libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar

how can I add a jar to a project like the the gson-2.2.4.jar and still make the app work with proguard?

the full code for proguard_project.txt

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-libraryjars /libs/gson-2.2.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar
```

Comment: there were no warnings

Comment: i just removed the gson-2.2.4.jar from the project and it works now without crashing while proguard is used, however when I add the jar back into the project it will crash when I install the newly created .apk file on the device and start it.  proguard not working when I add any jar to a project

Comment: or is this problem specific to the gson library?

Comment: try this sample proguard config: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg?r=878

Comment: i removed json library and the serialized class form obfuscation

Comment: added 3 lines form the code example from that link you mentioned, this is how the problem was fixed.  removed from obfuscation, the classes in gson that were causing problems and the inner class TestObject inside of MainActivity class that is the class object which is serialized by gson, -keepattributes Signature 
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; } 
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.MainActivity$TestObject { *; }

Comment: Are you sure the jar file is in /libs/ not ./libs/?  -libraryjars /libs/gson-2.2.4.jar maybe -libraryjars ./libs/gson-2.2.4.jar?

Comment: not sure, i removed that line in this project, but I have used /libs/jar_name.jar instead of the fully qualified name.  will research  to find out if this is the wrong synax.